# I have TemplateDoesNotExist at Django + AWS EB

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I make my app with djamgo + aws EB.
But I got error message.

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /item/wish_list/**

That works in my development env for now. But that doesn't work in my production env after deploying to EB.

/item/wish_list/ template is exactly in my development env.

I searched a lot of information. But I don't know yet.

Should I add something to 'DIRS'?

Please let me know.

***settings.py***

```
Django settings for ebdjango project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.12.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/


import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4n)79gz^3n1-_25%es4gdts9i083k09y(601h5)6mu+mr&bjl0'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['django-env.mwvc6f3kw3.ap-northeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com','127.0.0.1','52.193.171.91']

# ログイン用の設定
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/item/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'item.apps.ItemConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ebdjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
          os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ebdjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: You should take a look what template is used for `/item/wish_list/`. You probably forgot to deploy this template.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I have `/item/wish_list/` in my development env. What I deployed is not reflected in EB.

Comment: can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the path that you have written, I think because of this it didn't get deployed.